# Is it possible to get link of the scheduled post on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

I schedule post on Instagram via `business.facebook.com` but I cannot find the URL to the scheduled post. Is it possible? Thank you

Comment: Any luck solving this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :/